# square symbols appearing instead of spaces

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, character

I am working on a Wordpress site with the Lambda theme. On the client's computer (Chromebook) some spaces in the text are appearing as square symbols instead (but not all of them...).

I have been unable to recreate this issue on any computers, tablets or phones at my end... Here is what they see: [screencap from client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjxcF.png)

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Squares mean the client can't read the character code. Chances are it's not actually a space. It's possible one is using one method of encoding and the other is not. Make sure they are both set to the same (e.g. UTF-8)

Answer (score 0):

I can't find the lambda theme with my Add New Themes Dialog.  I see them on the web.  I wonder if they have recommended plugins that add new fonts to your system that you haven't loaded.